# NameError after packaging Python code

Tags: python, python-module

I've been using IPython for sometime without ever having to package code. I glanced through the following pages and setup a directory structure for my modules and now use IPython to initiate the program.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/

**Here is a gist of my setup**

**root foder**

1. modules(directory)

   1.1 external.py

   1.2 getdata.py
2. driver.ipynb

I created a directory called modules and created two files.

**modules (directory)**

-- external.py (contains the following)

```
import glob # and many other import statements
```

-- getdata.py (contains the following)

```
def funcname():
    file_list = glob.glob("Data/")

def other_func():
    x = x + 3
```

Now I run the following code in an IPython notebook

```
from modules import external
from modules.getdata import * 
# so that I can funcname() instead of modules.getdata.funcname()

other_func() # runs as expected
funcname() # NameError global name 'glob' is not defined
```

Running *glob.glob("Data/")* in the IPython notebook does not give out any error.

How do I fix this namespace issue without renaming any function? I have a dozen functions and they all have the same issue.

Edit 1:- I forgot to mention ***stuff that I've already tried***

import statement in getdata.py

```
import glob
def funcname():
    file_list = glob.glob("Data/")

def other_func():
    x = x + 3
```

I have more than one file which uses glob. Is there any better alternative other that importing modules in every file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `import glob` in `getdata.py` (**where the `glob` module is used**), not in the `external.py`.

```
import glob  # <--

def funcname():
    file_list = glob.glob("Data/")

def other_func():
    x = x + 3
```

Comment: I thought of that, won't is slow down stuff? I have a few files which use glob, so I'll have to import it in each and every file. Why doesn't my way work?

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal, `import` in other file does not affect other modules' namespace.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal, If a module is imported in a module, importing it again in another module does not reload it, but reused the already imported module.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal, You can experiment this with custom module which print something. Try import it once in a module, and in anothe module; you will see the thing is printed only once.

Comment: I was under the impression that it loads the function from the import files and could use the Namespace of the driver.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal, Each module has a its own namespace, not shared.

Comment: Is there any other way which will save me from making changes to each and every file?

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal, You can **pollute** builtin module which is searched last time, but not recommened; which will make your code hard to understand. Anyway here it is: `import glob; __builtins__.glob = glob` Put this line into the file where it is guaranteed always exectued / imported.